# Merging permissions and activity declaration from library AndroidManifest

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I have an android library distributed like aar file. For it integration user should declare some permissions in manifest and some activity.

Is is possible to declare it in libraries AndroidManifest so users do not need to worry about the manifest?

UPD. I figured out what was an issue. I take aar file form local maven repo, but except `aar` there was `jar` file with the same mane, and it takes it by default.

The solution is to change from `compile 'com.packagename:mylib:0.0.1'` to `compile 'com.packagename:mylib:0.0.1@aar'` in gradle dependencies.

Comment: Sorry, it is not possible.

Comment: *Is is possible to declare it in libraries AndroidManifest so users do not need to worry about the manifest?* Did you tried? [manifest merger](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/manifest-merger) is working in this way(at least with premissions)

Comment: @Selvin yes, I did. It does not include data from library to result manifest. Looks like it works only for buildTypes and Flavors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is is possible to declare it in libraries AndroidManifest so users do not need to worry about the manifest?

You can include such things in an `AndroidManifest.xml` file in your library. Through [the manifest merger process](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/manifest-merger), those items will be candidates for folding into the overall app's manifest.

However, users of your library may still have to "worry" about it:

- If you add an `<activity>` with the `<intent-filter>` for a launcher icon, some users of your library may not like that and have to take steps to block that icon
- If you add `<uses-permission>` elements that are scary, some users of your library may not like that and have to take steps to block those permissions

> It does not include data from library to result manifest

Yes, it does, at least for Android Studio/Gradle builds using actual AAR files. I do not know what "*like* aar file" means (emphasis added).

For example, in [this project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-cam2), I have [a manifest in my `cam2` library](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-cam2/blob/master/cam2/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml) several `<uses-permission>`, `<uses-feature>`,  and `<activity>` elements. In [a demo app's manifest](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-cam2/blob/master/demo/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml), I duplicate one of the `<uses-permission>` elements (as I forgot to remove it from the demo), and I override one of the `<activity>` elements (to have it run in a separate process). Everything else gets merged in unmodified.

Comment: Yes, it was my fault - I takes it from maven and does not add `@aar` in dependency